# How to load Cypher file into graph.db (Neo4j 3.5) quickly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have generated a cypher file which is having more than 50000 rows and wants to load it into neo4j 3.5 graph.db. When I copy and paste into localhost:7474/browser, it is taking hours time.

Any help loading these cypher statements (i.e., Cypher file) into Graph.db quickly?

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

A single Cypher statement should *never* be anywhere close to that large.

When importing data, the actual data to import should be in separate file(s) or other DBs, and you should be using the appropriate [import tools](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/data-import/).

Answer (score 0):

**Below worked for me:**

Neo4j 3.5:

Windows:

type D:\neo4j\import\Test | D:\neo4j\bin\cypher-shell.bat -u neo4j -p  --format plain

UNIX:
cat examples | bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p  --format plain

Neo4j 5.5:

cypher-shell -u neo4j -p

> :Source D:\neo4j\import\Test